# Верстка каркаса для ВЕБ-приложения

Tags: framework, html, вёрстка, css

Добрый день! Сегодня возник вопрос по поводу как лучше всего сделать эту страницу:

[image: screenshot]

Сама страница должна быть неподвижна, если мышкой скроллить над каким-то `DIV`-ом, то скролл должен появиться только у него. Понятно, что без `JavaScript`'а тут не обойтись.

Вот хотел бы узнать у вас, форумчане, есть ли для этих целей специальный велосипед? А если нет, то как бы вы поступили с ней.

Во `front-end`'е используется `Bootstrap`.

Буду рад помощи!

Comment: Либо фреймы, что не советую. Либо фиксируем размеры у областей и при превышении размеров overflow-y: auto или scroll

Comment: имхо auto изящнее...